# simple graph theory terminology question

Tags: terminology, graph-theory

This is a probably a no brainer, and I've been searching but can't seem to find an answer.  What is the term (and any alternate terms) for a graph with only two vertices and only one edge between them?

This is not a homework question :-)

Comment: Is that a straight line?

Comment: K2, aka a boring graph ?

Comment: I don't think so.  I was thinking something like "connection" if it is a network graph.  I see a couple of answers now, which are good, but I kind of thought it might be a simple one word term since it probably comes up in discussion a lot.

Comment: Belongs on http://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: @Ian Nelson: This is probably off-topic for mathoverflow.net -- too elementary.  The intended audience is "professional mathematicians, mathematics graduate students, and advanced undergraduates". I think the question is fine here on SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The complete graph on 2 vertices.  Denoted K<sub>2</sub>.  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph

Comment: I wouldn't say this is a standard but its the first thing that came to my mind.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Cory,  looked for how to do subscripts, but I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if an exact term exists, however it is a **[bipartite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) [complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) [planar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph) graph** with 2 vertices for sure.

Answer (score 0):

From further reading I found [Regular Graph entry on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph).  It would seem to be a "1-regular graph", though there are other graphs which also qualify as such.